# Problems while creating a hadoop client in my local machine

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hbase, elastic-map-reduce

I have a namenode and data nodes running on aws.
I configured foxyproxy and checked the following which are working:

```
 Ganglia Metrics Reports    master-public-dns/ganglia/
 Hadoop ResourceManager master-public-dns-name:9026
 Hadoop NameNode    master-public-dns-name:9101
```

My Java code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import com.google.protobuf.ServiceException;

public class HBaseConnection {

public static void main(String [] args){

    System.out.println("HBaseConnection");

}

public void getConnection() throws IOException, ServiceException{

    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.clear();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "MASTER_NODE_DNS");
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
    System.out.println("Getting HBaseConnection..");

    try {
        HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);
    } catch (MasterNotRunningException e) {
        p("HBase is not running.");
        p(e.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    QueryHBase query = new QueryHBase();
    query.run(config);



}

private static void p(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}
}
```

I am not able to connect to the master node and receive the following error:

```
14/10/23 07:17:35 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error,         closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

I have enabled all the ports in my master security group configuration.

This issue has been bugging me since quite sometime now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you connect to your Zookeeper ensemble, which may not be colocated with NameNode or ResourceManager. You should make sure `zookeeper-host:2181` is reachable.

Comment: I have my NameNode and DataNodes on AWS and am trying to connect them from my local machine.

I checked:

telnet dns 2181
and got 
    telnet: connect to address x.x.x.x Operation timed out
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: So, in a nutshell you should make sure you can connect to Zookeeper servers on port 2181 and to HBase Master on port 60000. Namenode and datanodes have nothing to do with it.

Comment: So to re state. I should be able to connect to my Hbase master on aws on port 60000. and slaves on port 2181?

Comment: After quick look at AWS developer guide it seems to me that both HBase Master and Zookeeper are located on master node, so you need to open ports 60000 and 2181 on **master**

Comment: Thanks for your effort @user3122114.

I am working on it and will keep you updated.

Comment: Nothing happens. I created a cluster on aws. Added custom TCP for port 60000 and 2181.

And it does not connect. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: [link](http://hbase.apache.org/book/trouble.client.html) 15.5.6. states that your error is caused by Zookeper being down or unreachable due to network issues, so you should focus on checking network and Zookeeper service status.

Comment: Ok. I'll get back on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is caused when HBase is compiled against Hadoop 1 and has Hadoop 2 jars on its classpath.
Make sure you are using same hbase version and compiling on correct hadoop